# Unable to fill 2 tables with data using one foreach loop with php

Tags: php

I have two tables in a `div` tag. What I want to do is to loop over the `$data` that contains the info that I want to pass into the `p` tags. The problem is that I want to use only one `foreach` (`$data` as `$val`).

Is it possible to loop to fill multiple tables with data using only one `foreach` loop ? I totally new to programming so some tips or examples would be great! I'd love to hear from you!

```
<div class="set">
    <div>
        <table class="table_0">
            <tr> 
                <th><p><?=$val</p></th>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>                   
        <table class="table_1">
           <th><p><?=$val</p></th>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no foreach loop in your example code. Can you show what you tried please? Also, `<?=$val` needs to be `<?=$val?>`

Comment: The reason I didn't post the foreach loop is because I end up making two of the foreach loops. I want to handle it with one foreach but have no clue how to do it. The only way I know is to loop the foreach and pass the datas for each tablesin two separates arrays, then relooping it again.

Comment: That's not even possible until/unless you want multiple tables rather than multiple rows..! So foreach records there will be 2 tables..

Comment: Please specify the $data you try to loop and conditions on how to separate that data into two tables.